# Spring integration Poller is not polling files which are coming to directory after application has started

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a spring batch-integration application where SI part reads a folder for files and invokes the spring job for that file. Now when i start my application it reads all the files available in the folder but if any file comes after the application started, poller doesn't pick that file. below is my code for the same

config

```
<int:poller id="appPoller" 
default="false" 
fixed-rate="1000"  
max-messages-per-poll="1" >
    <int:advice-chain>
<ref bean="inputDirChangeAdvice"/> 
</int:advice-chain>

</int:poller>
<bean id="inputDirChangeAdvice" class="com.varun.processor.ChangeDirAdvice" />
<int:channel id="files"/>

<int:channel id="requests"/>

<int:channel id="statuses">
    <int:queue capacity="10"/>
</int:channel>

<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter   id="pollAppFiles"
                                    prevent-duplicates="true"
                                    ignore-hidden="true"
                                    directory="file:/"
                                    filename-pattern="*.DAT"
                                    channel="files">
                                    <int:poller ref="appPoller"/>
                                <int-file:locker ref="appLocker"/>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
<bean id="appLocker" class="com.varun.locker.APPFileLocker" />

<int:transformer id="prepareJobLaunchRequest"
    input-channel="files" output-channel="requests">
    <bean class="com.varun.transformer.FileMessageToJobRequest">
        <property name="job" ref="JobName"/>
        <property name="fileParameterName" value="AbsoluteInputFile"/>
    </bean>
</int:transformer>

<int:service-activator id="runJob" method="launch" input-channel="requests"
    output-channel="statuses">
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.integration.launch.JobLaunchingMessageHandler">
        <constructor-arg ref="jobLauncher"/>
    </bean>
</int:service-activator>
```

I am using advice on poller so that poller read from dynamic location depending on some condition.

Update:

Advice code as below

```
public class ChangeDirAdvice extends AbstractMessageSourceAdvice {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("pollAppFiles.source")
private FileReadingMessageSource fileReadingMessageSource;


@Override
public boolean beforeReceive(MessageSource<?> source) {
    //calculate Dynamic directory location
    this.fileReadingMessageSource.setDirectory(newDirectory);
    return true;
}

@Override
public Message<?> afterReceive(Message<?> result, MessageSource<?> source) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good from the configuration perspective, plus this functionality is as an out-of-the-box. So, if it didn't work, we had so much JIRAs on the matter...

Try to minimize your application to isolate the problem.

For example don't use `inputDirChangeAdvice` and `appLocker`. And even just log messages and don't run the job.

Maybe some of them `stop()` your `pollAppFiles` and forgets to `start()`...

If you still sure that there is some bug from the Framework perspective, please, share through the GitHub as simple application as possible to play from our side locally.

Comment: I just noticed that if i run this application on windows machine, its picking the new file but when I move the application to UNIX machine its not. is there any restriction on file access level? Though i tried giving max permission to the file (777) , but still no response . . .

Comment: M-m-m. How about to give maximum permissions to the directory? Not familiar with such an issue. But that would be good to debug the application and place a break point onto `DefaultDirectoryScanner.listEligibleFiles()`. Also pay attention that you use `ignore-hidden="true"`. Be sure that your new files aren't such kind.

Comment: Just to be sure, `ignore-hidden="true"` keeps track of the file by fileName only, Right ! ! . b'coz for testing purpose, i am making copy of the same file in the folder.

Comment: ??? ` making copy of the same file in the folder`... Does `prevent-duplicates="true"` say anything to you? On background it is represent by the `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`. So, on Linux different `File` objects with the same name are considered as equal. Make sense for you?

Comment: this is something with my pollerAdvice. I removed pollerAdvice and locker both and SI is able to poll the static directory but when i add my advice to poller it polls once only. Update my question with my advice code.Not sure where i am going south..

Comment: OK. How about to return `ChangeDirAdvice` for the work, but still try without locker ?

Comment: I removed both locker and advice and its working fine, when I put advice back, it stuck

Comment: Would you mind sharing DEBUG logs for the `org.springframework.integration` category around the moment of directory changing. Including some log from your `ChangeDirAdvice` in the moment of dir changing. Plus that would be good to have some simple application to play from our side. OTOH maybe you again use the same directory as copy to test...

Comment: Ooops ... This is so bad. I had one bean defined in my config and it was breaking while loading the config when I deploy my application as war on server. But when I load my spring-config through `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` it doesn't break, that's why it was working on my windows m/c but when i was deploying it as war on unix, config load itself was breaking. I fixed those breaking beans (commented them as they were not being used) and after that its all working fine. . .

Comment: Now the question left here is that , should poller pick the file even if there is an error in loading the config (as i stated, it was picking the files already present in folder but wasn't picking any new files coming after)?

Comment: Yeah... The real world is unpredictable. We need to see what your bean does. The config isn't guilty at all. The problem is there somewhere in the code. So, just need to know what it does and analize and analize. I think that is already out of this thread scope. Was glad to be useful, if that!